# How to set a requirement of a dependency to my own repo

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having a multitude of issues where I will not pass npm audit due to prototype pollution in version of lodash bfore 4.17.15. I am usng the package join-monster, which uses stem/nesthydration, which has unupdated lodash packages. I have fixed the issues and pushed then to my own personal repo, but I do not know how to pont he dependency requirement to my won repo.

```
"join-monster": {
      "version": "2.1.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/join-monster/-/join-monster-2.1.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-Z/JJeDvQ8wS18rl1ytQ/teEiHXe90spTNqJmiUyRPQg/tREWTeY+meiAMTjqu8ltfsk6jer8TfDGUSoHil4Crg==",
      "requires": {
        "@stem/nesthydrationjs": "0.4.0",
        "debug": "^4.1.0",
        "deprecate": "^1.0.0",
        "generatorics": "^1.0.8",
        "graphql-relay": "^0.5.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15"
      },
```

In the above code, all I want to do is make the @stem/nesthydrationjs point to my won repo, instead of the 0.4.0 version that has severe vulnerability issues. Can anyone help?

Comment: In your `package.json` file, update the entry for `@stem/nesthydrationjs` to point to your Git repository. You *should not* edit your `package-lock.json` file manually: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies

Answer (score 1):

You should not directly edit the code in your `node_modules` directory. To resolve this issue properly, you have two options:

1. Fork the repository `@stem/nesthydrationjs`, make your changes there, and create pull request upstream. Then, update `package.json` to point at this new upstream version.
2. Fork the repository `@stem/nesthydrationjs`, make you changes, and update `package.json` to point at your fork.

Option 1 would be preferred because it contributes back to a free/libre/open source project. Option 2 might be used in the interim until the upstream accepts your pull request.

Comment: It is a dependency of a dependency, @stem/nesthydration js is never in my package.json. The only spot to point it is the requirement of the join-monster.

Comment: In that case you'll need to fork both `@stem/nesthydration`, and `join-monster`. Fix the lodash problem in `@stem/nesthydration`, and update `join-monster` to point at the fixed version of `@stem/nesthydration`.